# Set the order date of a product from an order

Tags: java, java-stream

I got a list with orders and each order has a list of products. What I try to do is to set the "orderDate" attribute of the product with the "created" attribute of the order. I done this using a for loop but I want to do this by using a stream and I don't know how to access the previous elements from the stream.

Here is my code:

```
//FOR EVERY PRODUCT SET THE ORDER CREATE DATE
    for(Order order:orders){
        for(Product product : order.getProducts()){
            product.setOrderDate(order.getCreated());
        }
    }

    orders.stream()
            .map(Order::getProducts)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(product -> {product.setOrderDate(Order::getCreated)}
```

Comment: I don’t see any point in forcing stream operations into this code. It’s just fine as it was. If you want, you may replace the inner loop with `order.getProducts(),forEach(product -> product.setOrderDate(order.getCreated()));`.

Answer (score 0):

Extracting the required value which needs to be mapped and holding it for all sub-records and then flattening the sub-records works out.For holding the common required value you could use apache utilities like [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) or use inbuilt jdk entry

```
        orders.stream()
                .flatMap(order->order.getProducts()
                                        .stream()
                                        .map(product->new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, Product>(order.getOrderDate(),product)))
                .forEach(entry->entry.getValue().setOrderDate(entry.getKey()));
```